Proof of absolute value of complex logarithm
I would like to prove that for a complex number z: $$\left| \text{Log}(-z) \right| \le \log \frac{1+|z|+|1+z|}{1+|z|-|1+z|}$$
Through numerical examples I already found that the equality only holds when z is a real number, and I can prove this equality mathematically, but I'm struggling to prove this inequality when z is a general complex number. Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Note: Edited to incorporate Lieven's comment.
Alternative formulation: $$\left| \text{Log}(z) \right| \le \log \frac{1+|z|+|1-z|}{1+|z|-|1-z|}$$

Do you define the complex logarithm in the usual way, with a discontinuity on the negative real axis?

Lieven: Yes, and for context, the values of z in my application space have mostly negative real values.

You could try putting $z=-re^{i\theta}$ and study both sides of the inequality as a function of $\theta$ with $r$ constant, knowing that both sides are equal for $\theta=0.$ In fact both sides reach a minimum at $\theta=0$ and the RHS goes to infinity near $\theta=\pi$ while the LHS stays very nicely bounded, but I haven't been able to close the gap. Also note that the fraction in the RHS is always between 0 and 1, so you can drop the large absolute value signs if you exchange the numerator and the denominator.
